# How to set pass-through authentication account in IIS?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-10

[image]

In IIS Mangager, I want to customize a site for an ASP.NET project. I want to use a custom pass-through authentication account.

What is the actual User name & password here?

Comment: There is nothing called "custom pass-through".

Answer (score 0):

The actual user name & password is local machine user account or a domain account. with passthrough authentication, IIS will attempt to use the actual identity of the user when accessing protected resources.

If the user is not authenticated, IIS will use the application pool identity instead. If pool identity is set to NetworkService or LocalSystem, the actual Windows account used is the computer account.